# Android - Suspected memory leak in ListViews - mEdgeGlowBottom

Tags: android, listview, memory-leaks

When running Memory Analyzer on my app i see for a few of my ListViews the following, eventhough im no longer in context of these views.

[image: mEdgeGlowBottom1]

[image]

Setting those ListViews with

> android:overScrollMode="never"

Seems to fix this leak but why is this happening ? What if i want to keep the glow effect ?

Thanks.

Comment: OS version? Seems like a framework bug, may have been fixed already or there may be a workaround.

Comment: @alanv Android 4.3. appreciate your help.